# How to include C11 headers when compiling C++ with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, c11

In a C++ project, I'm using a C library which includes some C11 headers. It won't compile with GCC. See this simple code:

```
// main.cc
#include <stdatomic.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Running `gcc main.cc -lstdc++`, it complains: `error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type`. However, `clang main.cc -lstdc++` works like a charm.
I'm wondering what makes the difference, and how can I compile it with gcc?

Comment: That library can't be used as is in C++. Different languages now more than ever. You'd need to wrap it.

Comment: There are syntax differences between the languages. When C says `_Atomic int` C++ uses templates and says `atomic<int>`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Any guide on how to wrap it?

Comment: No cookbook solution, I'm afraid. A general approach could be to create a header which uses opaque types only in the public interface, so it doesn't need to include anything from C11 in order to be compiled. Then you can use that in C++ source files.

Comment: @StoryTeller, yes fortunately there is a simple cookbook solution.

Answer (score 15):

To wrap C headers that use atomics, you may use the other spelling of `_Atomic` and define a macro that transforms this to valid C++:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
# include <stdatomic.h>
#else
# include <atomic>
# define _Atomic(X) std::atomic< X >
#endif

int foo(_Atomic(unsigned)* toto);
```

Both atomics interfaces have been developed in sync between the two committees, so besides syntax problems these should be binary compatible on any reasonable platform that provides C and C++.

Comment: I don't believe stdatomic.h is required to use the _Atomic keyword in C. That seems a better design than requiring a header.