# Is it possible to include a C header using C11 atomics without modification in C++?

Tags: c++, c, atomic, c11

I am attempting to write use the [this C library](https://github.com/dbittman/waitfree-mpsc-queue) **without modification** in a C++ application. It uses C11 atomics.

Consider the following program, which we can put in a file called `main.cc`.

```
#include "mpscq.h"


int main(){}
```

If I compile this with the `g++  -std=c++11 -c main.cc`, I get a whole collection of errors that look like the following.

```
usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stdatomic.h:68:9: error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type
 typedef _Atomic __UINT_FAST32_TYPE__ atomic_uint_fast32_t;
         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stdatomic.h:69:9: error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type
 typedef _Atomic __INT_FAST64_TYPE__ atomic_int_fast64_t;
```

**Is it possible to fix these errors without any modification to the library code?**

That is, I am willing to use whatever magic incantations are needed in my c++ code or my compiler flags, but I'd rather not change the library code.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343624/391161) but it requires modification of the header file.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I have compiled the library, but I can't include the header.

Comment: Can you write your own header file, providing `extern "C"` functions which you then implement in C?

Comment: Does wrapping `extern "C" {`...`}` around the `#include` directive help?  You should not directly include C header files in C++ code without it.

Comment: `extern "C"` affects linkage and names, but the problem here is with keywords and types.

Comment: @ChrisDodd It won't fix the problems. `_Atomic` doesn't exist in C++, but `_Atomic` [is used in the header file](https://github.com/dbittman/waitfree-mpsc-queue/blob/master/mpscq.h#L13)

Comment: As a clarification of what I meant in my previous comment: Can you provide a small C++ wrapper library? That is, provide a C++-compatible header file, but implement it in C using this C library.

Comment: @Justin, That's the workaround I'm currently exploring, but it feels like an unfortunate hack because there would effectively be two copies of a header file that look almost exactly alike.

Comment: @merlin2011 That's usually solved by having a single header file with `#ifdef` that generates different code in C and C++.

Comment: Interestingly, clang >= 3.6 seems to support this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/dqXpjlVoIXaZX9WE

Comment: See also: [P0943R1: Support C atomics in C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0943r1.html).

Comment: Oh, the advantages of opaque structures.  That interface would be a lot more robust had the `struct mpscq` been left incomplete.

Comment: Yes! Press the [New Issue](https://github.com/dbittman/waitfree-mpsc-queue/issues) button, fill in the details, and wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to fix these errors without any modification to the library code?

C++ does not have an `_Atomic` type qualifier, but the structure declared in the library header has members, including the first, with `_Atomic`-qualified type.  C++ will not accept this (and wrapping the header inclusion in an `extern "C"` block will not help).

C allows objects of `_Atomic`-qualified type to have different representations than objects of the non-`_Atomic` version of the same type, so in a general sense, this means that C++ cannot directly access any members of any instance of that structure.

If your C implementation happened to use the same representation for corresponding `_Atomic` and non-`_Atomic` types, then you could probably make your C++ compiler accept the header by `#define`ing the symbol `_Atomic` to an empty string, but this would be a gateway to more subtle bugs.  You could not expect C++ to provide the atomic access semantics that the library expects, so even in this case C++ cannot safely access the structure's members (directly).

If it is sufficient to manipulate instances of the `struct` only via the provided functions, then you can do so via opaque pointers.  Create a version of the header that provides a forward declaration of the structure, but no definition, and that provides all the function declarations (with C linkage).  You C++ code should accept the header and be able to call the functions, both receiving and returning pointers to instances of the structure that it must never try to dereference.

```
#ifndef __MPSCQ_H
#define __MPSCQ_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct mpscq;

struct mpscq *mpscq_create(struct mpscq *n, size_t capacity);
// other functions ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

If you need more than the existing functions provide, then you'll need to write additional helper functions, in C.

Comment: Are the two instances of `Atomic_` instead of `_Atomic` typos?

Comment: Note that names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__MPSCQ_H`) and names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation, and should not be defined in user code.

Comment: Yes, @Ruslan.  Fixed.

Comment: Acknowledged, @PeteBecker.  However, that aspect of the example code reflects the original header referenced by the OP.  It already being in the system, so to speak, retaining it may have practical benefit for the OP, in addition to the demonstrative purpose served by keeping it unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need wrapper for using that mpscq in C++ code but you need different
header to include it. That would work:

```
#ifndef MPSCQ_H_FOR_CPP
#define MPSCQ_H_FOR_CPP

extern "C"
{
    struct mpscq;

    mpscq *mpscq_create(mpscq *n, size_t capacity);

    bool mpscq_enqueue(mpscq *q, void *obj);

    void *mpscq_dequeue(mpscq *q);

    size_t mpscq_count(mpscq *q);

    size_t mpscq_capacity(mpscq *q);

    void mpscq_destroy(mpscq *q);
}

#endif
```

That said I would anyway write a wrapper to take care of RAII and such.