# stdatomic.h not found, for use in swift & metal compute shader

Tags: c++, gpu, metal

I'm trying to use a struct with an `atomic_int` for use in a metal compute shader. However, it says I need to import `#include "stdatomic.h"` - but every time I try, it can't find the file.

```
#include "stdatomic.h" // 'stdatomic.h' file not found
```

I'm trying to build my application for macOS Catalina

```
struct Fitness {
    atomic_int weight; // Declaration of 'atomic_int' must be imported from module 'Darwin.C.stdatomic' before it is required
    ...others...
};
```

- I have tried placing a copy of `stdatomic.h` into my project, but that gives a lot of compilation errors.
- My struct is defined in a `.h` header file.
- The struct is used by both Swift & Metal.
- I'm using XCode 11.4.

**Update:**
If I #include  in a .cpp file it works...why not a header?

Any ideas what is wrong? Can I not do what I want?

Comment: I wonder if this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45342776/10077

Comment: @Chris `std::atomic_int` is an alias for `std::atomic<int>`.  [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) is defined in the `<atomic>` header, not in the `"stdatomic.h"` header. Make sure you are compiling for C++11 or later.

Comment: #include <atomic> gives me a similar error: 'atomic' file not found

Comment: @Chris you didn't address the other part of my comment. Are you compiling for C++11 or later?

Comment: Apologies, My Xcode C++ Language Dialect is set to: GNU++14 [-srd=gnu++14]