# Can't build with libusb. ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, libusb

I am attempting to use libusb for a project and my C++ is rusty. I think I've resolved the dependencies for libtool and libdev on my ubuntu box, but now when I run, I get the following error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/include/stdatomic.h:40:9: error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type
```

I found [How to include C11 headers when compiling C++ with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342776/how-to-include-c11-headers-when-compiling-c-with-gcc), but not sure how this helps me.

The problem appears to be in gcc somehow, but not sure how to go about fixing it. I'm using C++ 20 in CLion.

Comment: Seems  more a C type than a C++ one. See [Atomic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) for example

Comment: @Damien but that doesn't help. I didn't pick the packages that libusb uses. Just trying to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on Ubuntu and I had tried

```
sudo apt install libusb
```

to no avail. On a hunch I tried

```
sudo apt install libusb-dev
```

And it worked, so now I don't need to build it.

I need to remember to search for the library name if it isn't obvious.